# Ruby - Can't replace last range's element with another one

Tags: ruby

So I want to merge overlapping ranges and it should like the following:
Input: ranges = [(1..2), (3..6), (5..8)]
Output: expected = [(1..2), (3..8)]
but when the code iterate over the intervals and goes to the else statement I just get a message "function_merge.rb:9:in `block in merge': undefined method`end=' for 2..19:Range (NoMethodError)"

I tried to save merged.last.end and interval.end to variables, rewrote the if statement over couple of lines (if interval.end > merged.last.end merged.last.end = interval.end end) but all that didn't work :-(

```
def merge(intervals)
  merged = []
  intervals.sort_by! { |interval| interval.begin }

  intervals.each do |interval|
    if merged.empty? || merged.last.end < interval.begin
      merged << interval
    else
      merged.last.end = interval.end if interval.end > merged.last.end
    end
  end
  return merged
end
```

I don't understand why I get this error message since "end" is a range method? I just want to "update" the merged.last.end with the interval.end number.
If you have any tips how to solve it, would be very nice :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sebastian points out, Ranges are immutable. Instead of trying to change the Range you'll have to make a new one.

```
def merge(intervals)
  merged = []
  intervals.sort_by! { |interval| interval.begin }

  intervals.each do |interval|
    if merged.empty? || merged.last.end < interval.begin
      merged << interval
    else
      merged[-1] = Range.new(merged.last.begin, interval.end, interval.exclude_end?)
    end
  end
  return merged
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didnt know that ranges are immutable  My code is finally working!

Comment: @chocowhiskey: It's easy to see in the documentation that there are no methods for changing the `Range`, ergo, it is immutable. For example, there is no method named `end=` in the documentation.

Comment: A bit of pre-processing is needed to remove ranges covered by another range. At present: `merge [1..4, 2..3] #=> [1..3]`. Also, you forgot to remove `return`. Better: `intervals.each_with_object([]) do |interval, merged|...`.

Comment: An edge-case problem: `merge(1..3, 3..2) #=> 2`.

Answer (score 0):

It has been explained that ranges are immutable. The question implies the elements covered by the ranges are all comparable (e.g, not `['a'..'z', 1..10]`). I assume that the array of ranges does not contain a mix of finite and infinite ranges.

**Solution**

*Code*

```
def distill(arr)
  a = arr.reject { |r| r.exclude_end? ? (r.end <= r.begin) : r.end < r.begin }.
          sort_by(&:begin)
  return [] if a.empty?
  combined = []
  curr = a.shift
  loop do
    break (combined << curr) if a.empty?
    nxt = a.shift
    if nxt.begin > curr.end
       combined << curr
       curr = nxt
    else
       last = [curr, nxt].max_by { |r| [r.end, r.exclude_end? ? 0 : 1] }
       curr = last.exclude_end? ? (curr.begin...last.end) :
         curr.begin..last.end
    end
  end
end
```

*Examples*

```
distill [5..8, 7...9, 9..11, 1...4, 38..37] 
  #=> [1...4, 5..11]

distill [1.5...2.2, 2.2..3.0, 3.0...4.5, 4.7..5.3, 5.2..4.6] 
  #=> [1.5...4.5, 4.7..5.3]  

distill ['a'..'d', 'c'..'f', 'b'..'g']
  # 'a'..'g'
```

*Explanation*

See [Range#exclude_end?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Range.html#method-i-exclude_end-3F).

The steps for the first example are as follows.

```
arr = [5..8, 7...9, 9..11, 1...4, 38..37]

a = arr.reject { |r| r.exclude_end? ? (r.end <= r.begin) : r.end < r.begin }.
        sort_by(&:begin)
  #=> [1...4, 5..8, 7...9, 9..11] 
a.empty?
  #=> false, so do not return
combined = []
curr = a.shift
  #=> 1...4 
a #=> [5..8, 7...9, 9..11]
```

The calculations within the loop can be best explained by salting the code with `puts` statements and displaying the results.

```
loop do
  puts "a.empty? #=> true, so break #{combined + [curr]}" if a.empty?
  break (combined << curr) if a.empty?
  puts "a.empty? #=> false"
  nxt = a.shift
  puts "nxt=#{nxt}, a=#{a}"
  puts "nxt.begin=#{nxt.begin} > #{curr.end} = curr.end = #{nxt.begin > curr.end}"
  if nxt.begin > curr.end
    combined << curr
    puts "combined << #{curr} = #{combined}"
    curr = nxt
    puts "curr = nxt = #{curr}"
  else
    last = [curr, nxt].max_by { |r| [r.end, r.exclude_end? ? 0 : 1] }
    puts "last=#{last}, last.exclude_end?=#{last.exclude_end?}"
    curr = last.exclude_end? ? (curr.begin...last.end) :
      curr.begin..last.end
    puts "new value of curr=#{curr}"
  end
  puts
end
```

```
a.empty? #=> false
nxt=5..8, a=[7...9, 9..11]
nxt.begin=5 > 4 = curr.end = true
combined << 1...4 = [1...4]
curr = nxt = 5..8

a.empty? #=> false
nxt=7...9, a=[9..11]
nxt.begin=7 > 8 = curr.end = false
last=7...9, last.exclude_end?=true
new value of curr=5...9

a.empty? #=> false
nxt=9..11, a=[]
nxt.begin=9 > 9 = curr.end = false
last=9..11, last.exclude_end?=false
new value of curr=5..11

a.empty? #=> true, so break [1...4, 5..11]
```

It is sometimes convenient to be able to return an empty (but valid) range such as 38..37; one should not think of empty ranges as necessarily being an indication that something is amiss.

**Alternative solution**

If the ranges are all finite, as in the example, and the combined sizes of the ranges is not excessive, one could write the following.

*Code*

```
def distill(arr)
  arr.flat_map(&:to_a).
      uniq.
      sort.
      chunk_while { |x,y| y == x.next }.
      map { |a| a.first..a.last }
end
```

*Examples*

```
distill [5..8, 7...9, 9..11, 1...4, 38..37] 
  #=> [1..3, 5..11]

distill ['a'..'d', 'c'..'f', 'b'..'g']
  # 'a'..'g'
```

*Explanation*

The steps for the first example are as follows.

```
arr = [5..8, 7...9, 9..11, 1...4, 38..37] 

a = arr.flat_map(&:to_a)
  #=> => [5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 2, 3]  
b = a.uniq
  #=> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 2, 3] 
c = b.sort
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] 
d = c.chunk_while { |x,y| y == x.next }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00005c2683af8dd0>:each> 
e = d.map { |a| a.first..a.last }
  #=> [1..3, 5..11]
```

One can convert the enumerator `d` to an array to see the elements it will generate and pass to `chunk_while`'s block:

```
d.to_a
  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

See [Enumerable#chunk_while](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while). One could alternatively use [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when).